# How to reply to a mail in Outlook(win app) using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, outlook, automation

I want to reply a mail in Outlook web application using Python. I'm using the package win32com.client for sending the mails but not getting anything regarding reply. Can anyone please share the code....

Comment: Can you share some codes for your web application?

Answer (score 0):

You find the Application Object API under 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/outlook.application
'replying to an E-Mail' is not generic, since you must look it up in you custom folder structure.

For introduction an example of the API usage (sending an e-mail):

```
import win32com.client as win32

if __name__ == '__main__':
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'someone@example.com'
    mail.Subject = 'Something important'

    # to set a text-body
    mail.Body = 'Lorem Ipsum'
    # for completness only, the html-body:
    mail.HTMLBody = '<h1>HTML Message body</h1>'


    attachment = "Path to the attachment"
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

    mail.Send()
    pass
```

Comment: Suppose there is no custom folder structure. Only inbox is there. Actually I have to reply to a mail chain every weekend after completion of a process and that mail comes in the "inbox" folder only . I can send email that's not a problem, I have to give reply to a particular mail which has a unique subject.